# VBA Error: Object Required - Works fine in 2007 but not in 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to paste charts from Excel to PPT slides. The macro works in 2007 but gives an error in 2013. How can I resolve this or force the ppt to open with 2007? (I have both on my computer).

It says 'Object Required' on the second line. (Looks like the object that is pasted loses it's selection in the slide or something)

```
Sheet7.ChartObjects("d1c11").Copy
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select
```

This is how I open ppt app.

```
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
pptApp.Visible = True
Dim myPPT As PowerPoint.Presentation
pptApp.Presentations.Open filename:=ppt_path
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the very latest Powerpoint Object library via your references.  Alternatively, you can utilize CreateObject like so:

```
Dim pptApp, myPPT
Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True
Set myPPT = pptApp.Presentations.Open(FileName:=ppt_path)
```

Comment: thanks! it looks to be in the right direction. However, the second last line of your code gives and error -> activex component can't create object. How can i correct it?

Comment: I just edited my answer.  We should be able to get that myPPT object from the PowerPoint.Application as "Powerpoint.Presentation" appears to be a descendant.

Comment: perfect. this is getting better. i think this last one should solve it completely. how do i define that myPPT is the file that has been opened by the last line of your code? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, in that case, you set myPPT to the return of the [Open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746171(v=office.15).aspx) which is a Powerpoint.Presentation object

Comment: thanks for your help! I made all the changes but unfortunately i am back to the same problem. It says Error 424: Object Required for line - pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select

Comment: this works absolutely fine on 2007 though but is not working with 2013. the macros stops after pasting the chart (as picture) in the slide

Comment: I just discovered (hit & trial) that this works on 2013 -> pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).ActionSettings.Application.Activate but this doesn't work on 2007. Is there a way i can specify which command to execute based on the version?

Comment: Where are you assigning pptSlide, can you post that?  You would need to reference it from `myPPT.slides(#)` or `myPPT.slides.Add` ...  As for the version you can use, `if pptApp.Version = "12.0" then ...` [check this out](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090616152844AAIQFWC)

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select
```

I have got error in similar line where it is pasting in powerpoint 2013 4 times and then the script stops while in 2007 the paste was done sucessfully along with the control going as per the flow defined.